# pandas read_csv column dtype is set to decimal but converts to string

Tags: python, csv, pandas, type-conversion, decimal

I am using pandas (v0.18.1) to import the following data from a file called 'test.csv':

```
a,b,c,d
1,1,1,1.0
```

I have set the dtype to 'decimal.Decimal' for columns 'c' and 'd' but instead they return as type 'str'.

```
import pandas as pd
import decimal as D

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'a': int, 'b': float, 'c': D.Decimal, 'd': D.Decimal})

for i, v in df.iterrows():
    print(type(v.a), type(v.b), type(v.c), type(v.d))
```

Results:

```
`<class 'int'> <class 'float'> <class 'str'> <class 'str'>`
```

I have also tried converting to decimal explicitly after import with no luck (converting to float works but not decimal).

```
df.c = df.c.astype(float)
df.d = df.d.astype(D.Decimal)
for i, v in df.iterrows():
    print(type(v.a), type(v.b), type(v.c), type(v.d))
```

Results:

```
`<class 'int'> <class 'float'> <class 'float'> <class 'str'>`
```

The following code converts a 'str' to 'decimal.Decimal' so I don't understand why pandas doesn't behave the same way.

```
x = D.Decimal('1.0')
print(type(x))
```

Results:

```
`<class 'decimal.Decimal'>`
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need converters:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import decimal as D

temp = u"""a,b,c,d
           1,1,1,1.0"""

# after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 dtype={'a': int, 'b': float}, 
                 converters={'c': D.Decimal, 'd': D.Decimal})

print (df)
       a    b  c    d
    0  1  1.0  1  1.0

for i, v in df.iterrows():
    print(type(v.a), type(v.b), type(v.c), type(v.d))

    <class 'int'> <class 'float'> <class 'decimal.Decimal'> <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Comment: [The `pandas` documentation is hilariously unspecific about what a `dtype` is](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes), but since I assume the implementation in `pandas` is based on `numpy`, [we luckily have `numpy` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). Do keep in mind that using generic objects can be more inefficient performance- and memory-wise than using basic `int` and `float`.