# Merge pandas DataFrame on column of float values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two data frames that I am trying to merge.

Dataframe A:

```
    col1    col2    sub    grade
0   1       34.32   x       a 
1   1       34.32   x       b
2   1       34.33   y       c
3   2       10.14   z       b
4   3       33.01   z       a
```

Dataframe B:

```
    col1    col2    group   ID
0   1       34.32   t       z 
1   1       54.32   s       w
2   1       34.33   r       z
3   2       10.14   q       z
4   3       33.01   q       e
```

I want to merge on col1 and col2. I've been pd.merge with the following syntax:

```
pd.merge(A, B, how = 'outer', on = ['col1', 'col2'])
```

However, I think I am running into issues joining on the float values of col2 since many rows are being dropped. Is there any way to use np.isclose to match the values of col2? When I reference the index of a particular value of col2 in either dataframe, the value has many more decimal places than what is displayed in the dataframe.

I would like the result to be:

```
    col1   col2   sub   grade   group    ID
0   1      34.32  x     a       t        z
1   1      34.32  x     b       s        w
2   1      54.32  s     w       NaN      NaN
3   1      34.33  y     c       r        z
4   2      10.14  z     b       q        z
5   3      33.01  z     a       q        e
```

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: I've edited the post to reflect the desired output.

Comment: @Megan In your join you have removed some rows. Check my answer on how to merge based on two columns. You can apply the additional logic after merging.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I edited the post to add the columns that I missed before, but I'm not sure what you mean about applying additional logic after merging.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a little hack - multiple float columns by some constant like `100`, `1000`..., convert column to `int`, `merge` and last divide by constant:

```
N = 100
#thank you koalo for comment
A.col2 = np.round(A.col2*N).astype(int) 
B.col2 = np.round(B.col2*N).astype(int) 
df = pd.merge(A, B, how = 'outer', on = ['col1', 'col2'])
df.col2 = df.col2 / N
print (df)
   col1   col2  sub grade group ID
0     1  34.32    x     a     t  z
1     1  34.32    x     b     t  z
2     1  34.33    y     c     r  z
3     2  10.14    z     b     q  z
4     3  33.01    z     a     q  e
5     1  54.32  NaN   NaN     s  w
```

Comment: Oh. Joining on decimal will not be accurate?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I think it is inefficient see this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114654/pandas-read-csv-column-dtype-is-set-to-decimal-but-converts-to-string/38114744#comment63666221_38114744)

Comment: Nice approach, but leads to even more subtle bugs due to rounding errors. Better use A.col2 = np.round(A.col2*N).astype(int)

Comment: @koalo - Thank you very much, I add it iot answer.

Comment: update in 2020: you can now just do np.round(col, decimals=2) . Not sure if this was previously impossible but it worked great for me and looked a little cleaner :)

Comment: The solution does not always work. Two numbers like 14.49999 and 15.500001 round to 14 and 15 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I needed to identify matching rows with thousands of float columns and no identifier.  This case is difficult because values can vary slightly due to rounding.

In this case, I used [scipy.spatial.distance.cosine](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) to get the cosine similarity between rows.

```
from scipy import distance

threshold = 0.99999
similarity = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(row1, row2)

if similarity >= threshold:
    # it's a match
else:
    # loop and check another row pair
```

This won't work if you have duplicate or very similar rows, but when you have a large number of float columns and not too many of rows, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column (col2) has **n** decimal numbers.

```
A.col2 = np.round(A.col2, decimals=n)
B.col2 = np.round(B.col2, decimals=n)
df = A.merge(B, left_on=['col1', 'col2'], right_on=['col1', 'col2'])
```