# comparing pandas dataframes on multiple columns and creating a master df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function to compare two DF's in order to create a new master DF containing the 'id' in DF1 and the '_record_id' in DF2 along with the lat and long by matching the lat's and long's of each row. This is an example of the tables I'm working with:

```
DF1            id   Latitude    Longitude
0     LA-DESI-A101  34.085778  -118.32779
1     LA-DESI-A102  34.086172  -118.327793
2     LA-DESI-A103  34.086511  -118.327791
3     LA-DESI-A104  34.0872    -118.327791
4     LA-DESI-A104  34.08707   -118.327594


DF2              id  _latitude  _longitude  _record_id
0      LA-DESI-A001  34.086511  -118.327791 acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-vvdasbhfgds
1      LA-DESI-B001  34.085778  -118.32779  acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voesadfegsd
2      LA-DESI-E004  34.086126 -118.324387  acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voplsadongg
3      LA-DESI-D005  34.086172  -118.327793 acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voasdkognoe
4      LA-DESI-D422  34.113367 -118.321414  acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voenposadkm
```

I'm still learning pandas and am not sure of the best way to go about this after researching for a while. I've tried using `np.where` but am unsure of how it actually works.. This is a sample of where I'm at with it...

```
def compare():
    cols = ['id', '_latitude', '_longitude', '_record_id']
    MASTER = pd.DataFrame()
    MasterDF = MASTER[cols]
    MASTER['id'] = 
    MASTER['_latitude'].astype(float) = np.where((df1['Latitude'] == df2['_latitude']))
    MASTER['_longitude'].astype(float) = np.where((df1['Longitude'] == df2['_longitude']))
    MASTER['_record_id'] =
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated...

Here's my full code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


data = []

def scrapePPLX(directory, filename):
    fname = open(directory, "r+")
    lines = fname.readlines()
    fname.close()

    if '_' in filename:
        polename = filename.split("_")[0]
    else:
        polename = filename.split(".")[0]

    for line in lines:
        if "<VALUE NAME=\"Latitude\" TYPE=\"Double\">" in line:
            lat = line.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
        elif "<VALUE NAME=\"Longitude\" TYPE=\"Double\">" in line:
            lon = line.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]

    data.append([polename,lat, lon])

def main():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.pplx'):
                scrapePPLX(os.path.join(subdir,file), file)

    cols=['id', 'Latitude','Longitude']
    PPLXdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
    PPLXdf.columns = cols
    PPLXdf.to_csv('PPLXcsv.csv',index=False)

    cols = ['id', '_latitude', '_longitude', '_record_id']
    readCSV = pd.read_csv(pdc)
    df = readCSV[cols]
    df.to_csv('newPDC.csv', index=False)

    compare(PPLXdf, df)

def compare(PPLXdf, df):

    PPLXdf['Latitude'] = PPLXdf['Latitude'].astype(str)
    PPLXdf['Longitude'] = PPLXdf['Longitude'].astype(str)

    df['_latitude'] = df['_latitude'].astype(str)
    df['_longitude'] = df['_longitude'].astype(str)

    masterdf = PPLXdf.merge(df, left_on=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], right_on=['_latitude', '_longitude'])
    masterdf.drop(['Latitude','Longitude'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    masterdf.to_csv('Master.csv', index=False)


print("Enter the directory to recurse: ", end='', flush=True)
rootdir = input()

print("Enter name of the PDC: ", end='', flush=True)
pdc = rootdir + "\\" + input()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Have you tried df1.merge(df2)?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Merge pandas DataFrame on column of float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135371/merge-pandas-dataframe-on-column-of-float-values), you could try to use pd.merge() but you need to be careful when you join since you have float values. It is safer to convert floats to integers. So, you could try something like this:

```
df1['latint'] = np.round(df1['Latitude']*1000000).astype(int)
df1['longint'] = np.round(df1['Longitude']*1000000).astype(int)
df2['latint'] = np.round(df2['_latitude']*1000000).astype(int)
df2['longint'] = np.round(df2['_longitude']*1000000).astype(int)
dfmerged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['latint', 'longint'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using pandas.merge function.

It will generate output but keep columns from both dataframes as column names are different. You will have to manually delete the columns which are not necessary.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value':         
np.random.randn(4)})    
right = pd.DataFrame({'key2': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'value': np.random.randn(4)})
```

There are two different column names 'key1 and 'key2' in differnt dataframes.

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', left_on=['key1'], right_on=['key2'])
  key1   value_x key2   value_y
0    B  0.410599    B  0.761038
1    D  1.454274    D  0.121675
```

Example2 : if there are multiple differnt columns to be merged then

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', left_on=['key1','value1'], right_on=['key2','value2'])
```

In your case a sample example for _latitude and _longitude is,

```
master_df = pd.merge(df1,d2,how='inner', left_on=['Latitude','Longitude'], right_on=['_latitude','_longitude'])
```

Then manually delete unnecessary columns

```
master_df.drop(['Latitude','Longitude'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = {'id': ['LA-DESI-A101','LA-DESI-A102','LA-DESI-A103', 'LA-DESI-A104','LA-DESI-A104'], 'Latitude': [34.085778, 34.086172, 34.086511, 34.0872, 34.08707], 'Longitude':[-118.32779, -118.327793, -118.327791, -118.327791, -118.327594]}
d2 = {'id': ['LA-DESI-A001', 'LA-DESI-B001', 'LA-DESI-E004', 'LA-DESI-D005', 'LA-DESI-D422'], '_latitude': [34.084511, 34.085778, 34.086126, 34.086172, 34.113367], '_longitude':[-118.327791, -118.32779, -118.324387, -118.327793, -188.321414], '_record_id': ['acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-vvdasbhfgds','acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voesadfegsd', 'acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voplsadongg', 'acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voasdkognoe', 'acbdefy-bbbb-cccc-b2c5-voenposadkm']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df1['Latitude'] = df1['Latitude'].astype(str)
df1['Longitude'] = df1['Longitude'].astype(str)

df2['_latitude'] = df2['_latitude'].astype(str)
df2['_longitude'] = df2['_longitude'].astype(str)

masterdf = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Latitude', 'Longitude'], right_on=['_latitude', '_longitude'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've gotten it to output with the rest of my code, but it doesn't seem to be behaving as I expected. When I run your sample code it outputs the 2 rows that are different, but when I run it on my larger DF's it output's a select number of rows (30 of ~850) that are already matching... any suggestions? I've added the rest of my code and accurate DF names to my question.

Comment: It really depends on what your expected result is: If you are trying to just bring _record_id from df2 into df1 then maybe a left merge is more reasonable then like so: ```masterdf = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['id', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'], right_on=['id', '_latitude', ' _longitude'], how='left')```

Comment: The main idea is to know what kind of [join](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/sql-joins-cheat-sheet/) to perform