# Loop through a list of dataframes and Merge them by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 982 dataframes and would like to loop through it so I can merge them by index. I intend to merge the dataframe in the position [0] with the dataframe in the position [1], then the dataframe in the position [2] with the result of the merging between the dataframe [0] with the dataframe [1] and so on.

I tried this but it didn't seem to work:

```
aux4 = '/Users/lucasiancsamuels/Desktop/Res. Regional - COVID 19/Bases/Auxílio Emergencial/202004_AuxilioEmergencial.csv'
auxabr = pd.read_csv(aux4,chunksize=50000,encoding='Latin-1',sep=';')

chunk_list = []  

#dividing the dataframe in chunks
for chunks in auxabr:  
    chunks.drop(chunks.columns[[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]],inplace=True,axis=1)
    chunks.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
    agrupado1 = chunks.groupby('CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE')
    auxemer1 = agrupado1['VALOR BENEFÍCIO']
    valor1 = auxemer1.agg(np.sum)
    chunks = (chunks.drop_duplicates('CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE'))
    chunks.index = chunks['CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE']
    chunks.index.astype(dtype=np.int64)
    chunks.sort_index(inplace=True)
    filtered_chunk = pd.concat([chunks,valor1],axis=1)
    chunk_list.append(filtered_chunk)

#merge the dataframes by index - didn't work
for i in range(0,981):    
    filtered_data = pd.merge(left=chunk_list[i],right=chunk_list[i+1],on=chunk_list[i].index)
```

And gives back this error:

```
KeyError: Float64Index([1200013.0, 1200054.0, 1200104.0, 1200138.0, 1200179.0,
              1200203.0],
             dtype='float64', name='CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE')
```

Comment: So as I understand it, the error message informs you that the merging fails because some of your indices are float64 dtype. Try casting index columns to int when reading csv by adding option: `dtype={'CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE' : 'int'}`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135371/merge-pandas-dataframe-on-column-of-float-values) may be helpful to you.

Comment: @pavel already tried that - it didn't work because the dataframe has some NaN values, after realizing that I set na_values = 0 and still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, I started writing another comment but it's coming a bit too long for comfort.

Firstly, `na_values` doesn't do what you think it does. This option is used when you have additional values you want pandas to treat as NaN. For example I can have `-99` values in my spreadsheets indicating no value and when I load the csv I would instruct pandas to treat those as NA with `na_values=-99`.

What you need to do is: first load the csv as per usual, then use `fillna` to remove NaN values and finally cast the entire column to integer:

```
auxabr = pd.read_csv(aux4,chunksize=50000,encoding='Latin-1',sep=';')
auxabr['CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE'].fillna(0, inplace=True, axis=1)
auxabr = auxabr.astype({'CÓDIGO MUNICÍPIO IBGE':'int'})
```

It should all work after that.