# How to round a no index dataframe in Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dask

I was trying to merge 2 dataframes with float type series in Dask (due to memory issue I can't use pure Pandas). From [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135371/merge-pandas-dataframe-on-column-of-float-values), I found that there will have issue when merging float type columns. So I tried the answer in the post accordingly, to get the XYZ values * 100 and convert into int.

```
x                       y                       z                   R   G   B
39020.470001199995750   33884.200004600003012   36.445701600000000  25  39  26
39132.740005500003463   33896.049995399996988   30.405698800000000  19  24  18
39221.059997600001225   33787.050003099997411   26.605699500000000  115 145 145
39237.370010400001775   33773.019996599992737   30.205699900000003  28  33  37
39211.370010400001775   33848.270004300000437   32.535697900000002  19  28  25
```

What I did

```
N = 100
df2.x = np.round(df2.x*N).astype(int) 
df2.head()
```

But since this dataframe has no index, it results in a error message

```
local variable 'index' referenced before assignment
```

Expected answer

```
x       y       z       R   G   B
3902047 3388420 3644    25  39  26
```

Comment: I recommend providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and got it to work this way:

```
df2.x = (df2.x*N).round().astype(int)
```

If you need to round to a specific decimal:

```
(df2.x*N).round(2)
```