# Pandas dataframe round underlying data (not just how it's displayed)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

You may say this has been done before, but all solutions I can find fail, allow me to demonstrate:

first of all here are my imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

values are naturally, not rounded.

```
df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].sum()
> 1924961.5499999998
```

1st attempt:

```
df['bar'] = df['bar'].round(2)

df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].sum()
> 1924961.5499999998
```

2nd attempt:

```
df['bar'] = df['bar'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))

df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].sum()
> 1924961.5499999998
```

3rd attempt:

```
df['bar'] = np.round(df['bar'], decimals=2)

df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].sum()
> 1924961.5499999998
```

What am I missing? perhaps it's a version thing?

```
!pip show pandas
> Name: pandas
> Version: 0.23.3
> ...
```

Lastly, here's one thing that is really weird:

```
df['bar'].sum()
> 298730861.26

df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].sum()
> 1924961.5499999998
```

I don't even know what to do with that. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
df['bar']
3          50.00
4          50.00
5          50.00
6           0.00
11          0.00
15        271.07
17         50.00
18         -0.34
21       3814.81
22          0.00
           ...  
491834      0.00
491835    337.55
491836     50.00
491844    400.00
491847     50.00
491853    300.60
491856      0.00
491864     50.00
491865     50.00
491868    400.70
Name: bar, Length: 154918, dtype: float64
```

Should `dtype` be `object`? or `string`?

4th attempt:

```
df['bar'] = df['bar']
df['bar'] = df['bar'].astype(str)

# in order to sum I have to convert back to float and the underlying data remains
df[df['foo']==foo]['bar'].astype(float).sum()  
> 1924961.5499999998
```

Comment: If they are not strings, there's always the risk of floating point precision.

Comment: What's the source? You may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38114744/5386938

Comment: @JustinEzequiel data is coming from a database, maybe I can apply converters after the fact, instead of on ingestion?