# A way to apply converters to pandas.read_sql?

Tags: python, pandas

After [learning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38114744/9148880) I have to apply the `converters` argument (and not `dtype`) to have a pandas column of `decimal.Decimal` class, I tried doing it with a module I'm using to access SQLite databases. However, while this argument is implemented in `pd.read_csv` and is available as a kwarg in `pd.read_excel`, that is not the case with `pd.read_sql`:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table', myconnection, converters={'somecol':decimal.Decimal})
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-abdc559366bb>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table', myconnection, converters={'somecol':decimal.Decimal})

TypeError: read_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'converters'
```

Is there any way to do the conversion natively? The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) for the function indicates `pd.read_sql` doesn't allow for any kwargs at all.

If not possible, which would be the most recommended solution? I could do with `df['somecol'] = df['somecol'].apply(decimal.Decimal)`, but I'm wondering if there is a less verbose way in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is found in [SQLite3's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=register_converter#sqlite3.register_converter) own documentation, through the `register_converter` function and then calling an argument on the connection:

```
import sqlite3
from decimal import Decimal

def conv(i):
    # Converts a number input to decimal.
    return Decimal(str(i))

sqlite3.register_converter('REAL', conv)

con = sqlite3.connect('something.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
```

This way all numbers stored as real in SQLite will be automatically converted to `Decimal` upon reading.

---

**Obs:** note that the string conversion before decimal in the `conv` function happens in order to preserve the state of the number (although calling `conv(1.1+2.2)` will result in badly-formed decimals anyway.